# Interrupt trigger on presence of a pwm signal

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, interrupts, pulse, hall-effect

In order to detect the presence of a pwm signal using a microcontroller from an external sensor (an interrupt), say the sensor is a hall sensor rotary encoder that is used to count the number of rotations and the direction of rotation of a motor shaft using a magnet attached to the shaft, what is the most trivial way to accomplish the task?

Comment: Modified according to the suggestion. Now please shed some light. Thanks 

Comment: `most trivial way` is opinion based ... hardware person will choose hardware solution ... software person will choose software solution ... opinion based questions are off topic here

Comment: Feed pwm to RC and sense Vc if delays are acceptable. Or sense pwm directly with uController and set some maximum alowable timeout when pwm disapear.

Comment: If you only want to detect the *presence* of such a signal.... AC-couple, rectifier, peak-detect, LED

Comment: @jsotola Yes. I'm asking for your opinion in deed. Every problem has numerous ways to solve. Thanks

Comment: like I said before, questions asking for opinions are off topic here ... it is up to you to attempt a solution and post a specific question if you get stuck